# How to use static variable in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, static-variables

How can use static variable in qt?

I tried:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QObject>

class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = 0);
    static int a;
signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

but I can't read the data.

```
int b = Test::a;
```

Comment: ***but I can't read the data.*** Why can't you read the data?

Comment: Where are you defining the static? Where are you initializing it?

Comment: ***How can use static variable in qt?*** The exact same way you do so in c++.

Comment: Is it giving an error or just not getting value

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: You use it the same way you use in any other situation.

Comment: Try to add this at the top of test.cpp outside of any function "int Test::a = 0;"

Comment: By the way, static variables are not specific to Qt.  You could write a `main` function without Qt to test the concept.